# Unable to use the same formula for different rows in excel

Tags: excel-formula

[image][image]I am using a Substitute Formula to replace a character '?' with '@'. But the formula isnt working as desired for the other rows when i drag the formula downwards.

The same output gets copied for others rows too. This happens even though the formula for other cells corresponds to its respective cells[image].

Please help!!!

Comment: Please show your formula.

Comment: Attached the formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is fine; it works correctly for me.

I can replicate your behaviour by setting the spreadsheet to manual calculation, so my thought is that yours is too.

You can check the setting from the `Formula` tab on the Ribbon. Click the `Calculation Options` item to see the current setting.

If it is manual, change to Automatic and your formulae should work as expected.

Comment: I changed the settings from Manual to Automatic. Its working fine now.